# Is it permissible to offer salah in a shirt that contains pictures?

Tags: halal-haram, salat

I have Shirt that contains a Cartoon picture, for better understanding "Living Thing Picture"

Can I offer Salah in it ?

If yes then it would be as normal as in simple dress? or will be consider as Makrooh or any thing else?

What if I dont have any other option but to left the salah, instead of offer in that shirt ?

Answer with Reference will be appreciated.
Jazak Allah

Answer (score 1):

It is not permissible to wear clothes having pictures of animate (camel etc.) on them. Salaat with such clothes will be Makrooh (reprehensible). Please refer to [this Q&A from AskImam](http://askimam.org/public/question_detail/903.html); a site that I personally consider quite authentic.

N.B.: I do not work for or have any affiliation with AskImam.com.

Answer (score 0):

It's makrooh. Makrooh means, you can do it but there are better ways to do it. So Islam suggest you to not to do it. However in the end, Allah will judge your prayers and your submission to Him. If you have no time to change your clothes and you will miss your prayer, do your prayers with your pictured clothes. It's better you do your prayers.

You can find some references from here: [Ruling on praying in a room in which there are images](https://islamqa.info/en/161222)

And maybe you can look to differences between makrooh and haraam: [The difference between haraam and makrooh](https://islamqa.info/en/9084)