# Is it okey to pray salah in a room where I have my own pictures?

Tags: salat

Please kindly provide me an expert answer need to clear this confusion. 
Because according to me I'm not worshiping my own picture so how its effect my values....

Kindly need a proper answer. TIA.

Answer (score 1):

It's makrooh. Makrooh means, you can do it but there are better ways to do it. So Islam suggest you to not to do it. However in the end, Allah will judge your prayers and your submission to Him. Doing your prayers in any condition is better than not to do because of some pictures.

Remember that, these rules for not committing sins like "shirk" and to able to do your prayers in better way. If you feel you are doing your prayers with no problem in a room with pictures, it's your decision to call it shirk or not. No body can judge you but Allah.

Allah knows the best.

You can find some references from here: [Ruling on praying in a room in which there are images](https://islamqa.info/en/161222)

And maybe you can look to differences between makrooh and haraam: [The difference between haraam and makrooh](https://islamqa.info/en/9084)

This is adapted answer of mine in [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/30949/3466)