# Is it haram to pray salat while wearing a shirt with the Polo Ralph Lauren logo (featuring someone playing polo on a horse)?

Tags: salat, image

I have the [Polo Ralph Lauren](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ralph_Lauren_Corporation) logo on the left side of my shirt. Is it permissible for me to pray salat while wearing it?

[image: Ralph Lauren logo]

Comment: related http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/17944/is-it-permissible-to-offer-salah-in-a-shirt-that-contains-pictures/30949#30949

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is permissible. The face of both the horse and the rider is unclear in this logo. Ibn Abbaas (RA) said:

> "**The image is the head.** **So if the head is cut off, it is no longer an image.**" -- [Source](https://islamqa.info/en/220161)

Shaykh Ibn Uthaymeen said:

> "If the image is not clear – that is, it does not have eyes, a nose, a
> mouth or fingers – then this is not a complete image and is not
> competing with the creation of Allah, may He be glorified and
> exalted."
>
> Quote from, Majmoo Fatawa ash-Shaykh Ibn Uthaymeen (2/278-279)

Since the image is not haram, it is halal for you to wear this shirt and pray while wearing it.