# Can I wear clothes with images on it

Tags: halal-haram, clothing, image

Is it haram to wear clothes that have images of living/made up "animate" things like wearing a shirt of the character in an animated t.v show etc. I don't know what to do, I looked into many other sites but they were not helpful.

Comment: I've seen a similar (answered) post on the site unfortunetly I couldn't find it by any key word so far to mark it as a duplicate :(. I hope someone else can do so.

Comment: A related post https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/35550/is-it-haram-to-pray-salat-while-wearing-a-shirt-with-the-polo-ralph-lauren-logo

Answer (score 2):

The most accepted opinion is that images are haram, especially when it involves designs of creations which do not exist in real life as if it is a challenge to the designs of Allah - and on Judgment Day, they will be commanded to give life to these designs they made, yet of course it is impossible. There are various ahadith on this, but I will choose the most appropriate one here for the situation that is asked about:

> عَنْ عَائِشَةَ ـ رضى الله عنها ـ قَالَتْ دَخَلَ عَلَىَّ النَّبِيُّ صلى
>   الله عليه وسلم وَفِي الْبَيْتِ قِرَامٌ فِيهِ صُوَرٌ، فَتَلَوَّنَ
>   وَجْهُهُ، ثُمَّ تَنَاوَلَ السِّتْرَ فَهَتَكَهُ، وَقَالَتْ قَالَ
>   النَّبِيُّ صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏ "‏ مِنْ أَشَدِّ النَّاسِ عَذَابًا
>   يَوْمَ الْقِيَامَةِ الَّذِينَ يُصَوِّرُونَ هَذِهِ الصُّوَرَ ‏"‏‏.‏ 
>   Narrated `Aisha: The Prophet (ﷺ) entered upon me while there was a
>   curtain having pictures (of animals) in the house. His face got red
>   with anger, and then he got hold of the curtain and tore it into
>   pieces. The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "Such people as paint these pictures
>   will receive the severest punishment on the Day of Resurrection."
>   (Bukhari).

We can therefore understand that wearing it would be worse, if even displaying it inside angered the Prophet to that extent. At the least, we can say it is doubtful (if anyone isn't convinced by the above), and we are commanded to stay away from doubtful matters.

To read the various ahadith on images, see: https://sunnah.com/search/?q=pictures

Comment: **<comments deleted>** Comments are intended for constructive criticism for the purpose of improving the answer, not for arguing about which interpretation of Islam is "more correct".