# Is it haram to design tshirt and sell it online?

Tags: drawing, cartoon, movies, fashion-design

I am a Graphics Designer. I want to design t-shirt and then upload it to some online marketplace, where I can sell it.

So, the problem is, I want to use Anime (Japanese Animation based on manga/comics) related stuff like logo, magical-sign (indeed it's fake, just for fantasy), sign, quotes.

I know, we can't use the picture, that's are prohibited. But, I am not using images tho. I want to use Anime kind of reference and sell it to those anime fans.

Anime is haram some point. It depends on what type of anime you're watching. There is good anime and bad anime too. I am not gonna drag those stuff. I just want to use some particular things that fans would like to buy.

Simply put: Its like I want to use the Marvel Avenger movie logo and quotes on t-shirts. And sell it to fans.

So, would it be a promotion of anime/movies, if I use those mentionable things? it would be haram?

Last thing I want to ask. Anime is non-living, non-existing characters. I heard that, if we create drawings of living creatures, then it would be haram. But anime is non-existing. So, it would be permissible to use them on T-shirts. Even it would be troublesome while praying with those shirts. By the way, these shirts are not for me, I just want to sell them to a particular country like the USA.

Please, let me know the answer. This kind of thing bothers me too much. I am getting confused between haram and halal.

Comment: There should be nothing wrong with the shirt design part. But during salah it is an issue: https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/45425

Comment: Besides the drawing of anime part in Islam, legally you won't also be able to sell copyrighted stuff like those of Marvel/DC logos,  characters and quotations. They will take your stuff down.

Answer (score -1):

Iam not a scholar but according to me u can design tshirt but u should not draw any portrait or any haram thing on it can the tshirt should cover awrah of the person who is wearing it