# Is it acceptable to Praying with Animals' logo T shirts

Tags: halal-haram, salat, clothing, image

Some of My T shirts or Football Jerseys have Images of Animal's logo Like lion, Tiger etc so 
Can I pray with these logo's T shirts 
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIoob.jpg)

Comment: See also [Is it haram to pray salat while wearing a shirt with the polo ralph lauren logo](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/35550/is-it-haram-to-pray-salat-while-wearing-a-shirt-with-the-polo-ralph-lauren-logo)

Answer (score 2):

It is considered *makruh* to pray in clothes which have an image of a living thing on them.

> *  <sub>English translation is my own, so may contain mistakes</sub>
>
> فقال الحنفية - كما في الدر وحاشية الطحطاوي - يكره للمصلي لبس ثوب فيه تماثيل ذي روح
>
> The saying of the Hanafis - ... - is that it is disliked for a praying person to be wearing clothes that have images of a thing with a soul
>
> ...
>
> ونص الشافعية - كما في أسنى المطالب - على أنه يكره للمصلي أن يلبس ثوبا فيه تصوير
>
> The view of the Shafi'is - ... - is that it is disliked for a praying person to be wearing clothes that have an image
>
> <sup>— [الموسوعة الفقهية](https://archive.org/stream/FPmfkmfk/mfk12#page/n126/mode/2up)</sup>

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can pray in them since they are acceptable simply because these pictures don't contain anything improper or Haram in Islam such as women with inappropriate clothes, wine, curses, bad words, and the like.

But keep in mind that what you wear should also cover your 'Awrah which is between your navel and knees.

There are verses and Ahadiths that forbid some things explicitly which means they mustn't be on your clothes in pictures form, like:

**- Wine and gambling:**

In [Surah Al-Baqara (2) - Verse 219](https://quran.com/2/219):

In Arabic (the original text):

> ...يَسْـألُونَكَ عَنِ الْخَمْرِ وَالْمَيْسِرِ قُلْ فِيهِمَآ إِثْمٌ كَبِيرٌ وَمَنَافِعُ للنّاس وَإِثْمُهُمَآ أَكْبَرُ مِن نَّفْعِهِمَا

Its translation:

> They ask you about **wine** and **gambling**. Say, "In them is great sin and [yet, some] benefit for people. But their sin is greater than their benefit."

**- Bad words:**

In [Surah Al-Isra (17) - Verse 53](https://quran.com/17/53):

In Arabic (the original text):

> وَقُل لِّعِبَادِي يَقُولُواْ الَّتِي هِيَ أَحْسَنُ إِنَّ الشَّيْطَانَ يَنزَغُ بَيْنَهُمْ إِنَّ الشَّيْطَانَ كَانَ لِلإِنسَانِ عَدُوًّا مُّبِينًا

Its translation:

> And tell My servants to **say that which is best**. Indeed, Satan induces [dissension] among them. Indeed Satan is ever, to mankind, a clear enemy.

**- Women:**

In Surah [Al-Nisa (4) - Verse 34](https://quran.com/4/34):

In Arabic (the original text):

> فَالصَّالِحَاتُ قَانِتَاتٌ حَافِظَاتٌ لِّلْغَيْبِ بِمَا حَفِظَ اللَّهُ

Its translation:

> So **righteous women** are devoutly obedient, guarding in [the husband's] absence what Allah would have them guard.

---

If you found a verse, Hadith, or even Fatwa that forbid football and animals, then you can consider them unacceptable *in Islam* to have on your shirts and clothes, **and it appeared that there are already some sayings for significant scholars that state it as disliked which have been mentioned in this** [**dedicated answer**](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/55751/34139)